# No permission to use google internal application sharing

Tags: google-play-console

After uploading my .APK to Google Play Console for Internal Application Sharing, I get the message: You don't have permission to use internal app sharing for com.mygame.myappl.

I know that a similar question has been answered by Sonia Aug 20 at 15:05 but it did not help me because:
a) I am an authorized uploader, since as the Play Console account owner, I created a list in "App releases->Internal app sharing->Manage uploaders" including my email (i.e. my google account email).
b) I don't understand the Sonia answer item 2)  i.e. check that "you are using your published application ID...". I don't have any "published application ID" since, following Google procedure to publish myappl.apk, I just defined a Title, included game description, requested Icons etc..  I have never been asked about any applicationID by Google Console.
My .APK is the first one I am trying to upload. I developed it and its applicationID is com.mygame.invaders as defined in build.gradle. And I don't have any other APK uploaded.
Can you help, please?

Comment: Is your app available in production? It's a requirement to be able to use internal app sharing.

Comment: In play console, after logging in for the first time,  I "created" the application, filled up the "store listing" form (at least partially - in draft), then in App Releases inserted myaccount email (see my previous description).  I chose internal app  sharing because it easily allows early phase testing - at least this is my understanding. It is not ready for production (i.e. to be open to public use).

Comment: I would like to point out that the complete message is "Upload failed - You don't have permission to use internal app sharing for com.mygame.myappl" and comes up after the upload reaches 100%, and immediately after the "processing..." message.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

**First of all I like to make it clear here, we don't need to publish app in release mode, to use "Internal App Sharing" feature.**

> I don't understand the Sonia answer item 2) i.e. check that "you are using your published application ID...".

This means: We need to first published our app in "Internal test track". See my screenshot.[Google Console Internal test track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXTRC.png)

*You can select your app from Google play Console, then select "App Release" from left Nav bar. After that Scroll down to "Internal test track" option. And select "Manage".*

This is true, we don't need to publish app in release mode, but still we need to fill the all details, Like: "Store Listing", "Content Rating", "App Content", and "Pricing & distribution". You should see GREEN checkbox for all these options.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works the way you are saying. I just erroneusly thought that I could use the internal app sharing without publishing first  in the "internal test track".

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your account is whitelisted to be able to upload for internal app sharing?

See "Add authorized uploaders" in https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479?hl=en

Comment: I created a list (in App releases->Internal app sharing->Manage uploaders), added my email (the one I use to login in play console) and checked the list. Could the problem be related to the APK (maybe the APK manifest)? The error comes at the "processing" phase, immediately after 100% downloaded APK.